# QGIS 3 heatmap, on screen color ramp with data scale

Tags: qgis, color, heat-map, color-ramp

When making heatmaps in qgis 3.0.1 i would like to place the color ramp with percentage and actual numbers for the bin borders on the map.

Each marker under the color ramp represent a percentage of the max value. So at a maxvalue of 4000, the marker at 50% would represent 2000.

Is it posible to access the actual number for each marker/bin or at least the maximum value for the heatmap/color ramp? One could then do the rest manualy.

[image]

Comment: As a quick work around. You can export the data to Excel. Set up the Bins there and you'll have the value ranges you can work with

Comment: If you have two screens you can have Excel open on one and QGIS on the other. You could save the Excel file in the folder with your output for future reference or tinkering.